# Getting the number of elements with .length is inaccurate?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page on the admin side of a website I'm working on. This page is for adding images to a product listing. I use jQuery to count the number of thumnails on the page (which is equal to the number of pictures assigned to the product) and when there are 5, it removes the button to add more pictures. This should effectively limit the number of images allowed to be uploaded to 5.

The "add picture" menu has three categories. You can use an URL, use an image you've previously uploaded, or upload a new image.

The only time I'm leaving the page is to upload a new image. When a new image is uploaded a form is submitted and the page resets. For some reason, jQuery is not registering the new image on the reload.

This is located near the top of the script. This script is in an external JS file that is included just before the closing body tag:

```
var pictureCount = $(".thumbnail-container").length;
if (pictureCount == 5) {
    $("#add-picture").hide();
} else {
    $("#add-picture").show();
}
```

This is the function that is called anytime an previously uploaded image is added, or an image is added from an URL. (I also use this same function to reduce the picture count when a thumbnail is removed):

```
var removeAddButton = function(operator) {
    if (operator == "+") {
        pictureCount++;
    } else if (operator == "-") {
        pictureCount--;
    }
    if (pictureCount == 5) {
        $("#add-picture").hide();
    } else {
        $("#add-picture").show();
    }
};
```

Each thumbnail has a picture, and a button which removed the thumbnail located in a `div` with a class of `thumbnail-container`. By defining the variable as the number of elements with the class of `thumbnail-container` when the pages refreshed (When a picture is uploaded and the POST goes through) the page should load knowing how many pictures are there.

However, after I upload an image the count is still 0. If I upload another image, it is 1. I have confirmed this with an alert and a console log. Strangely, if I run the first snippet, but cage it in a `window.onload` anonymous function, the page knows the count on the reload. However, when I wrap the snippet in `window.onload`, the second snippet doesn't affect the count when the function is called.

Why is this? How can I fix the issue?

P.S.

When the new image is uploaded, PHP takes care of adding the new thumbnail to the page. Since PHP gets finished before the JS starts, it should know the count.

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Comment: @Epodax, note the last sentence in my question. I wanted to be thorough when asking my question, and for all I know it could have something to do with PHP, although I seriously doubt it. If requested, I would be happy to assign a different tag.

Comment: @Allenph php is server side and js client side: so php is parsed completely before the page is even sent to the client browser. The two has not any relation between them. Your issue is only on the js side even if there are options you can do the same with php on the server side

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I'm aware of that. I was just being thorough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first script is inside the window load event handler then if it is working, then you can create `pictureCount` as a global variable as below then set its initial value on the load event handler so that the `removeAddButton` will be able to access it

```
var pictureCount = 0;
$(window).load(function () {
    pictureCount += $(".thumbnail-container").length;
    $("#add-picture").toggle(pictureCount != 5);
});

var removeAddButton = function (operator) {
    if (operator == "+") {
        pictureCount++;
    } else if (operator == "-") {
        pictureCount--;
    }
    $("#add-picture").toggle(pictureCount != 5);
};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Didn't think to use `.toggle()` either, thanks for that.